# Creating a matrix in Python storing the rightmost index of the string character

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a matrix where it stores the rightmost index of the string character. For example, if i have the string:

```
"baby"
```

i want to generate a matrix as such:

```
[['b',2],['a',1],['y',3]]
```

where the index 0 represents the non-duplicate character in the string and index 1 represents the rightmost index occurence of the character in the string. Example, the first character 'b' occurs at index 0 but another occurs at index 2, hence, it will be 2.

I tried something like:

```
def str_matrix(string):
    matrix = [[]]
    for i in range(len(pattern)):
        if pattern[i] not in matrix:
            matrix.append([pattern[i],i])
        else:
            matrix[i][1].append(i)

    print(matrix)
```

but I'm getting:

```
[[], ['b', 0], ['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['y', 3]]
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Comment: @DeepSpace no the order doesnt matter

Comment: See my answer then

Comment: @DeepSpace my bad, i confused myself with alphabetical order. In this case, i want it to be b, followed by a and y, similar to the relative order of the original string.

Comment: `[(char, string.rfind(char)) for char in set(string)]` Edit: this works, but doesn't keep the order of letters - I supposed that it doesn't matter.

Comment: @FilipHappy much appreciated but i prefer the lengthy for loop, similar to the style i wrote as I'm more comfortable with that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `OrderedDict` to dedupe:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> s = "baby"
>>> OrderedDict((k, v) for v, k in enumerate(s))
OrderedDict([('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('y', 3)])
>>> [[k,v] for k, v in OrderedDict((k, v) for v, k in enumerate(s)).items()]
[['b', 2], ['a', 1], ['y', 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
txt = 'baby'
res = [[i, len(txt) - txt[::-1].find(i) - 1] for i in set(txt)]
res
# [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['y', 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since @Maxxx stated that the order doesn't matter (but the original answer is ordered) and Maxxx prefers explicit/readable form (not a one-liner), I will provide one here:

```
def str_matrix(string):
matrix = []
chars = set(string)  # only unique letters from the string
for char in chars:
    right_most_index = string.rfind(char)
    matrix.append([char, right_most_index])
```

Edit: I suggest not using string as name, because string is name of one of python's default libraries. Also for better performance use tuples instead of list (as in the one-liner provided in my initial comment on the answer ;)